# Carbon-14 formation in atmosphere

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity

Wikipedia says Carbon-14 is formed in the atmosphere by the reaction:

1n + 14N → 14C + 1p

This looks like neutron capture. However, I would expect neutron capture to result in 15N. However, "proton emission" seems to be a rare phenomenon:

15N → 14C + 1p

So, my first question is, does the reaction happen in two stages, or is the proton ejected "immediately"?

Secondly, is this overall type of reaction 1n + → + 1p common? Are there any other examples of such reactions, other than with 14N?

Comment: If you insisted on writing this as a two step process, which may or may not be reasonable, the correct intermediate state would not be $^{15}\mathrm{N}$ (which would imply the system was settled), but $^{15}\mathrm{N}^*$ to make it explicit that the intermediate state is excited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a prompt (immediate) reaction, and is more usually written something like N14(n,p)C14 to indicate that.  It is far from the only such reaction.

EDIT - To quantify my statement that there are many similar reactions, I went to the Evaluated Nuclear Data Files site hosted at Brookhaven ([ENDF](http://www.nndc.bnl.gov/exfor/endf00.jsp)), entered 'n,p' for the reaction, 'sig' for the desired quantity (sig = sigma = cross-section in barns for the reaction).  This returned 308 separate data sets, from He3(n,p)H3 to Bi209(n,p)Pb209.  So, indeed, the existence of the N14(n,p)C14 reaction is no great surprise.